# Sending email successfully. But got 503 statuscode. Heroku, NodeJS, Nodemailer

Tags: node.js, heroku, nodemailer, http-status-code-503

I Have issue with sending email from my react app. I have BE in nodeJS deployed on HEROKU. For sending emails I'm using Nodemailer. The point is that everything works fine. Email is sent and deliver. But I don't know why I'm getting 503 status code.

I read heroku documantation where it says that the reason why is that can be infinite loop. But I think I don't have infinity loops here.

Thank you for any kind of help.

Here is my code:

```
const express = require("express");
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post("/send", async (req, res) => {
  console.log("req: ", req.body);
  const output = `
    <p>You have a new contact request</p>
    <h3>Contact Details</h3>
    <ul>  
      <li>Name: ${req.body.firstName}</li>
      <li>Email: ${req.body.email}</li>
      <li>Phone: ${req.body.phoneNumber}</li>
      <li>Created: ${req.body.createdAt}</li>
    </ul>
    <h3>Message</h3>
    <p>Hi there</p>
  `;
  
  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: process.env.MAIL_HOST,
    port: process.env.MAIL_PORT,
    secure: true, // true for 465, false for other ports
    auth: {
      user: process.env.MAIL_USER, 
      pass: process.env.MAIL_PASSWORD, 
    },
  });

  // send mail with defined transport object
  try {
    await transporter.sendMail({
      from: "test@test.sk", 
      to: "info@test.sk", 
      subject: "Hello ✔", 
      text: "Hello world?", 
      html: output, 
    });
    console.log("Objednávka bola úspešne odoslaná");
    return res;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error: ", error);
    return error;
  }
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;

app.listen(port, () => console.log("Server started"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not sending back any response from your POST handler, you're either returning `res` or `error`, both of which don't do anything in Express, which means requests will never properly end.

Instead, send back a proper response to end the request:

```
return res.end();             // for a normal situation
return res.status(400).end(); // for an error situation
```

It's up to you if you want to send back some text, or to set another status code that's more appropriate in your app.